# Relationship between $f$ and $f^{-1}$ unclear

Tags: general-topology, functions

Say I have the function from $f:X \to Y$,

$f(x) = 3$ when $x \ge 0, \ = 0$ when $x < 0$. $X$ and $Y$ both with the standard topology.

Hence $f^{-1}(y) = [0, \infty)$ when $y = 3, = (-\infty, 0)$ when $y = 0$.

Now consider $(2, 4)$ open in $Y$.

$f^{-1}(2, 4)$ contains $3$ so it will map the point $3$ to $[0, \infty)$ and all other points of $(2, 4)$ will get mapped to the empty set. So $f^{-1}(2, 4) = [0, \infty)$.

Now consider $f(f^{-1}(2, 4)) = f([0, \infty))$ = 3

But $f(f^{-1}(2, 4))$ = $(2, 4)$ as $f$ and $f^{-1}$ inverse operations.

So my understanding must be incorrect as this does not make sense. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: $f$ is left inverse to $f^{-1}$ only if $f$ is surjective

Comment: So what is $f^{-1}(2, 4)$?

Comment: $f^{-1}(2,4)$ is $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

What you are confusing are the concepts of inverse function and inverse image of a function, which are, quite confusing, usually denoted by the same symbol, but are equivalent only if the function is invertible. So, a function $f: X\rightarrow Y $ is invertible if $f$ in injective and surjective, i.e. for any $y\in Y$ you can find a unique $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. If the function $f$ is not invertible, you can still define the inverse image, still denoted by $f^{-1}$ of $f$. Let $y\in Y$, then $f^{-1}(y)$ is empty if $f$ is not surjective and $y$ is not contained in the image of $f$. Even if you consider surjective functions, the inverse image of $f$ is not a function unless $f$ is also injective. Everything you say is correct but for the last statement: $f(f^{-1}(2,4)=3\neq (2,4)$ as $f$ is not invertible hence $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are not inverse operations in the usual sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful with the concept of inverse function! A function $f:X \to Y$ has an inverse if it is bijective! In this case the 'inverse function' $f^{-1}$ isn't even a function (recal to the definition of a function), since one element of a domain goes to more than one element of the range! So that's why we cant say it is a inverse function of $f$. The consequence of that is the contradictaory result that you are pointing out.

But this is good example to illustrate why do we need bijection for claiming that a function has an inverse.